# Get index of first list and use it in another list

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I have two lists:

```
List1 has values like: "A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, C... so on
List2 has values like: "0, 1, 2, 2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 4, 4, 4, 4.... so on
```

I want to get index of List1 with values of lets say B and find corrosponding values in List2. 
What i am doing is getting start and end index of List1 where value is B. Than looping through list2 for those indexes and getting values. This seems like too much work and lot of overhead. Is there a better way of doing this using linq?

I used this: var `list1Values = list1.FindAll(x => x.Contains("B"));` This gives me values from B i am stuck after this like how can i get corresponding values from list2 after this? As findAll dont even give index. One thought is to loop through index of list1Values and get list2 values but dont think that is right way to do it.

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I used this: var list1Values = list1.FindAll(x => x.Contains("B"));  This gives me values from B i am stuck after this like how can i get corresponding values from list2 after this? As findAll dont even give index. One thought is to loop through index of list1Values and get list2 values but dont think that is right way to do it.

Comment: Please update your question with this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided both lists have the same length, you could use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to pair up the corresponding items from both sequences:

```
var target = "B";
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (x,y) => Tuple.Create(x,y))
                  .Where(o => o.Item1 == target);

foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item2);
}
```

I used a `Tuple`, so `Item1` is the letter from `list1` and `Item2` is the corresponding item in `list2`. Of course you could've used an anonymous type and given it a more meaningful name instead.

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that you tagged the question with C#-3.0. In that case, use the solution below. `Zip` and `Tuple` were introduced in .NET 4.0. The solution below uses the `Select` method, which was available in .NET 3.5. Both solutions use LINQ, so you need to add the namespace: `using System.Linq;`

Another solution is to use the overloaded [`Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) to get the indices of the target letter, then grabbing the items from the second list based on those indices.

```
var target = "B";
var targetIndices = list1.Select((o, i) => new { Value = o, Index = i })
                         .Where(o => o.Value == target);
var query = targetIndices.Select(o => list2[o.Index]);

foreach(var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: I dont see Zip under my list1? My list1 is string list like: var list1 = new List<string>();

Comment: @NoviceMe `Zip` is a LINQ extension method added in .NET 4.0. I've updated my answer to use a C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5 solution instead. Make sure you've added `using System.Linq;` to your C# file to import the required namespace.